# Can't write on external HDD after upgrading to OS X El Capitan

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, macos

I am using a LaCie external hard disk in my MacBookPro for 3 years. After having updated to OS X El Capitan, I am no longer able to write on the HDD and I have read-only privileges. Info shows that the HDD is formatted in NTFS but, before upgrading, I was able to both read and write on the hard disk without any problem and without any external app.
Any suggestions to solve this issue?

[Update]: I have installed Tuxera NTFS and now everything works fine. Before I had other applications that are no longer valid for El Capitan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install Tuxera NTFS or Paragon NTFS, OS X is not able to write on NTFS.

http://www.tuxera.com

https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/

**Edit :**

A free solution : http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfsfree/

Comment: Thanks @MrMojoRisin, but do you know why, before updating to El Capitan, I was able to write on my HDD without any of those programs?

Comment: You certainly had a ntfs software before ;)

Comment: I do not know if Apple has removed it in OS X El Capitan however previous versions of OS X has had NTFS Write Support natively for some time now, it's disabled by default... probably for licensing reasons and performance too. There are no native utilities to deal with filesystem corruption either. It's slower then using e.g. Tuxera NTFS.  All one needs to do is set the appropriate entry in the `/etc/fstab` file to enable NTFS Write Support natively on a given volume without the use of a third-party utility. Have a look at: http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/

Comment: @user3439894 thanks for this piece of history :) I didn't know that !

Comment: @user3439894: please, switch your comment to an answer :). We have already enough answers which are just nice comments to overflow the stack.

Comment: Does this still work for macOS Sierra? It gives me compatibility issues while trying to install and the installer quits.

Comment: NTFS for Mac® 14 -> Support for macOS 10.12 Sierra

Answer (score 2):

This link worked for me http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/ but I have a seagate drive, might work with others.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Seagate drives you can download a free driver from here: [Paragon Driver for Mac OS](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may have to do with USB power.  My portable drive without an external power source can not mount (though it shows in system report and the light flashes).  A drive with external power and the same formatting mounts without issue.